# Query prometheus counter across multiple instances

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I got several instances exposing a Prometheus counter and would like to aggregate all values over a certain period of time. I've been trying a lot of different things but can't get it working.

Let's assume my metric name is request_total. This metric has facets for `path` and `status_code`. My goal is to get an overall sum of this counter, without filtering it by any of its facets. If I run `sum by (instance) (request_total)`, I get the following graph from Prometheus:

[image]

As we can see my counter seems to be correct for each instance. However, if I try to sum all those values with `sum (request_total)`, I get the following result:

[image]

I'm pretty new to Prometheus but was expecting that the counter would actually not be reset and better cumulative. Could you please help me and tell me what I am missing here ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `sum(request_total)` should work and show the result across all the instances, and according to your graphs that's exactly what it does:

until ~8:30am there are two instances that report 4 and 11 requests, total of 15 which you can see in the second graph.

from ~8:33am to 8:42am only one instance reports one request and then another instance starts reporting one request as well which shows as going from 1 to 2 on the second accumulative graph.

Comment: Hi Nir,

Thank you for your answer. Now I understand why I'm getting this result. Do you know what I should query to get a cumulative value over a certain period of time ? Like getting a graph with value 15, then 16, then 18 in my example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @vesna IIRC doing something like: `sum(rate(request_total[5m]))` will give you the average requests per second over time-windows of 5 minutes

Comment: If you're using Prometheus UI you can switch to "graph" mode and then you can also set the off-set of how long back in time you want to view

Comment: Well I actually figured out where my issue came from. The thing is that my counter does not get reset at startup time which relates to this issue: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1673. I picked a workaround from the issue and it seems to work well. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer to my questions !

Answer (score 2):

It is OK if Prometheus [counters](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) are periodically reset. If you need to get the total counter increase across multiple time series with graceful handling of counter resets, then wrap [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function into [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum). For example, the following query would return the total number of requests over the last year:

```
sum(increase(requests_total[1y]))
```

Note that this query needs to load and scan raw samples on a year-long time range ending at the current time. So it may be quite slow. You may adjust the lookbehind window in square brackets according to your needs. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations) for possible time durations.

Note also that Prometheus may return fractional results from `increase()` over time series with integer samples. This is due to extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. This issue has been solved in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) - see [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) and [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) for technical details. MetricsQL also provides [running_sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) function, which can be used for drawing cumulative increase over the sum of counters. For instance, the following query returns a line, which starts from 0 on the left side of the graph and increases over the selected duration according the the cumulative increase of the sum of all the `requests_total` series, e.g. it returns cumulative number of requests over the selected time range:

```
running_sum(sum(increase(requests_total)))
```